# I need some guidance on what to do next with my server

Tags: centos, hardware-rec, nginx

I have a server with the following specifications:

- HP DL180 G6
- 2 x Intel Quad-Core Xeon E5620
- 8GB RAM
- 4 x 2TB Hard drives running in a RAID10
- NGINX running as download webserver

It is connected at Leaseweb.com via a 1GB port.

I have about 30-40 people downloading constantly at the same time. However with this many users at the same time the download speed is very slow.

What can I do to speed this up?

Do I just need to buy another server or is there something a little cheaper that I can do to get it to where I need it.

Comment: You havent given enough information.  Where is the bottleneck?  Is it disk IO?  Network Bandwidth?

Comment: So this is a fileserver with a web gui?

Comment: Here is my ATOP http://i45.tinypic.com/vz4pj.jpg

Comment: Here is HTOP, any others that I can post?   http://i47.tinypic.com/3310u47.jpg

Comment: Also IOtop   http://i47.tinypic.com/sdgt5e.jpg

Comment: @Keltari here is the stats

Comment: @MDMoore313 I use webmin if that is what you mean

Comment: @Blackhawk1xx I just wanted to know what service this server provides.

Comment: @MDMoore313 It is just a fileserver all it does it give downloads for people

Answer (score 0):

Where is the server hosted, and what upload speed do you have on the connection.

If it is hosted at home on an ADSL connection, then you wont really be able to speed it up, as your upload speed will be low.

If its hosted in a datacenter, then, you may need to ask for an increase in your port speed.

Comment: Leaseweb.com with 1GB port